# Polymer 1.0 page.js or app-router

Tags: routes, polymer, frontend, polymer-1.0

Hello what are the pros and cons of using page.js or app-router as my routing components for a polymer 1.0 app? Which one should I use?

Thank you

Comment: take some time going thru the respective demos and also look at more-routing  https://github.com/PolymerLabs/more-routing

Comment: Use dna-router to create routes in html only. Also, its very user friendly.
https://github.com/Saquib764/dna-router

Answer (score -1):

You can try [dna-router](https://github.com/Saquib764/dna-router). Through this you can create routes in HTML.

For more info, visit : https://github.com/Saquib764/dna-router